# Why does merely including Ceres headers cause link errors, due to missing symbols?

Tags: c++, lnk2019, ceres-solver

I am trying to use [Google's *Ceres* optimizer library](http://ceres-solver.org/index.html) for the first time.
And I couldn't get their "Hello, World!" example to build on my Windows 10 machine.
I was left with 8 unresolved symbols during the link.
I pruned my test case until finding that merely including the Ceres headers was enough to cause the missing symbol link errors; I don't even need to call any Ceres library functions!

This simple code:

```cpp
// Quick check of Windows build flow, for console apps.
#include <iostream>
// #define GLOG_NO_ABBREVIATED_SEVERITIES
// #include "ceres/ceres.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

builds and runs just fine:

```
davibana@5CD3141WXZ MINGW64 ~/prj/<foo> (master)
$ make hello_world
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64 10.0.18362.0 '&&'  cl.exe //EHsc hello_world.cpp //Fohello_world.obj //I"C:\Users\davibana\prj\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.7.6
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86_x64'
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.37.32825 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello_world.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.37.32825.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hello_world.exe
hello_world.obj
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64 10.0.18362.0 '&&'  link.exe //OUT:hello_world.exe //MACHINE:X64 hello_world.obj "C:\Users\davibana\prj\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\ceres.lib" "C:\Users\davibana\prj\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\glog.lib" "C:\Users\davibana\prj\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\gflags.lib"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.7.6
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86_x64'
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.37.32825.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Hello, World!
```

But, if I uncomment lines 3 and 4:

```
$ make hello_world
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64 10.0.18362.0 '&&'  cl.exe //EHsc hello_world.cpp //Fohello_world.obj //I"C:\Users\davibana\prj\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.7.6
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86_x64'
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.37.32825 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello_world.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.37.32825.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hello_world.exe
hello_world.obj
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAXH_N@Z (public: void __cdecl std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool))' defined in 'libcpmt.lib(cout.obj)' is imported by 'hello_world.obj' in function '"class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@PEBD@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '?widen@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEBADD@Z (public: char __cdecl std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::widen(char)const )' defined in 'libcpmt.lib(cout.obj)' is imported by 'hello_world.obj' in function '"class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::endl<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z)'
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAHD@Z (public: int __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char))' defined in 'libcpmt.lib(locale.obj)' is imported by 'hello_world.obj' in function '"class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@PEBD@Z)'
hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __cdecl std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::tie(void)const " (__imp_?tie@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEBAPEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (??0sentry@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAA@AEAV12@@Z)
hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __cdecl std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::rdbuf(void)const " (__imp_?rdbuf@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEBAPEAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@PEBD@Z)
hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: char __cdecl std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::fill(void)const " (__imp_?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEBADXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@PEBD@Z)
hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (__imp_?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry(void)" (??1sentry@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAA@XZ)
hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & (__cdecl*)(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &))" (__imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@P6AAEAV01@AEAV01@@Z@Z) referenced in function main
hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::put(char)" (__imp_?put@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@D@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::endl<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z)
hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (__imp_?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@XZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::endl<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z)
hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (__imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAA_JPEBD_J@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char const *)" (??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@PEBD@Z)
hello_world.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
make: *** [GNUmakefile:118: hello_world] Error 2
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Why are you mixing MinGW and msvc?

Comment: @drescherjm, because I need to produce a redistributable Windows DLL.

Comment: I think that is what is causing the linker errors / conflict between different implementations of the standard library but I may be wrong.

Comment: Aha! I needed to add the "/MD" compiler option to CFLAGS. Working now.